How to draw symbols over the edge of the plot?
I got linechart from this code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == "__main__":
    res_files=([1],[2],[3],[4])
    marker_list = ['bo-', 'gv-', 'rD--', 'c*--', 'mh:', 'ys:']
    label_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    j = 0
    for i, res in enumerate(res_files):
        data = res_files
        x = np.arange(0, len(data))
        ax.plot(x, data, marker_list[i], label=label_list[j])
        j = (j + 1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(data), 1.0)) #rotation=0, visible = True 
ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
plt.ylabel('abc')
plt.xlabel('dcf')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.05', color='black')
plt.show()

which looks like this:

My question is:
How can you draw the 2 points at the end outside the plot as shown in the second picture?


Any one can help me?

There are two steps to this. The first step is to change the z-order of the plots, so that they are drawn over the axis (see docs for more info). This is done by adding the parameter zorder to each ax.plot(...). To draw over the axes anything above 2.5 is sufficient, so I recommend a value between 2.5 and 3.
The second step is to make sure the plot doesn't clip on the sides. To do this, set_clip_on(False) can be used.
So, ax.plot(...) should be changed to:
line = ax.plot(x, data, marker_list[i], label=label_list[j], zorder=2.6)[0]
line.set_clip_on(False)

